# SonarQube Rules ignored

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, sonarqube, sonarlint

Projekts in IDE(Eclipse and IntelliJ) are bind to its corresponding project on SonarQube(6.7.4)-server with SonarLint-Plugin(Eclipse:3.3.1.201712071600 IntelliJ: 4.0.0.2916). For every project on the server the same quality profile is set.

But when checking classes (java) with SonarLint the rules are "ignored" in some projects (but not in every project). E.g. the "Locks should be released"-rule of SonarAnalyzer(Java).

Any ideas if there is something wrong with the SonarLintPlugin, the Sonarqube-server? The binding should be correct, because in some projects it works.

SonarLint config:

[image]

SonarQube project config:

[image]

Comment: can you share your sonar configuration?

Comment: Added them to the qustion